# How is availability zone list order determined by the nova api in openstack?

Tags: openstack

I want to change the default option for availability zone in my openstack setup in horizon. However, I am having trouble finding out what determines the order of the availability zones as returned by the nova api. For example, running `openstack availability zone list` I get:

```
+--------------+-------------+
| Zone Name    | Zone Status |
+--------------+-------------+
| zone2        | available   |
| zone1        | available   |
| internal     | available   |
| zone3        | available   |
+--------------+-------------+
```

which is the same order as in horizon's dropdown box. However, querying the database directly, I get:

```
mysql> select * from aggregate_metadata;
+---------------------+------------+------------+----+--------------+-------------------+--------------+---------+
| created_at          | updated_at | deleted_at | id | aggregate_id | key               | value        | deleted |
+---------------------+------------+------------+----+--------------+-------------------+--------------+---------+
| 2015-06-12 08:43:07 | NULL       | NULL       |  1 |            1 | availability_zone | zone1 |       0 |
| 2015-06-12 08:43:08 | NULL       | NULL       |  2 |            2 | availability_zone | zone2 |       0 |
| 2015-10-26 05:30:15 | NULL       | NULL       |  3 |            3 | availability_zone | zone3 |       0 |
+---------------------+------------+------------+----+--------------+-------------------+--------------+---------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Obviously, the openstack api is doing some sorting before returning the result... however, I can't figure out  how it is being sorted nor how I could control the sorting.

Answer (score 0):

[get_availability_zones](https://github.com/openstack/nova/blob/master/nova/availability_zones.py#L112) is the function used by nova api to collect list of availability zones.

This function gets list of available services(which is sorted based on the id) ,adds availability zone name is added to those services.

Since service list is the first step it's id defines the order and not the zone name.

The sort order can be modified in different ways based on the requirement.

1. Sort the order at frontend (horizon)

   Modify [this line](https://github.com/openstack/horizon/blob/f54339f316d4559b2a79b6f70108ce0076870f52/openstack_dashboard/dashboards/project/static/dashboard/project/workflow/launch-instance/details/details.html#L30) with

   ```
   ng-options="zone.value as zone.label for zone in model.availabilityZones | orderBy:'value'"
   ```
2. Sort the order at backend (nova-api)

   Add

   ```
   available_zones.sort()
   not_available_zones.sort()
   ```

   before return statements in get_availability_zones function